# How to use subdomains in laravel app on local ubuntu?

Tags: laravel, subdomain

Looking at https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#route-group-subdomain-routing I try to make subdomains for my laravel 10 / livewire 3 app on my
home kubuntu 22.04

In routes/web.php I added :

```
Route::domain('{company}.'.config('app.url'))->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', HomePage::Class);
    Route::get('/news-details-page/{slug}', NewsDetailsPage::Class)->name('news.details');
    Route::get('/news{news}', NewsListingPage::Class)->name('news.listing');
});
```

and in app/Livewire/HomePage.php :

```
class HomePage extends Component
{
    public string $companySlug = '';
    public $selectedCompany;

    public function mount(?string $companySlug = '')
    {
        $this->companySlug = $companySlug;
        $this->selectedCompany = Company::getBySlug($this->companySlug)->first();

        if (empty($this->selectedCompany)) {
            $this->selectedCompany = Company::getByActive(CompanyActiveEnum::ACTIVE)->first();
        }
        ...
    }
```

I run server with command :

```
php artisan serve
```

But url in browser

```
http://main-office.127.0.0.1:8000
```

where "main-office" is slug of one of companies.

does not work, browser use it for search.

In route aputputs I have :

```
GET|HEAD  {company}.127.0.0.1:8000/ ................................................................................................................................................ generated::UVdHOKqavkOQwvfV › App\Livewire\HomePage

GET|HEAD  {company}.127.0.0.1:8000/news-details-page/{slug} ................................................................................................................................ news.details › App\Livewire\NewsDetailsPage

GET|HEAD  {company}.127.0.0.1:8000/news{news} .............................................................................................................................................. news.listing › App\Livewire\NewsListingPage
```

Which way is correct? Have I to add any subdomain/company in /etc/hosts of my OS ?

**UPDATED # 1:**

In .env I changed :

```
APP_URL=localhost
```

and cleared cache

In browser try to run url

```
http://main-office.localhost
```

Then apache default page is opened

On

```
http://main-office.localhost:8000/
```

My App is opened but shows

```
404 NOT FOUND
```

error

Which way is correct ?

**UPDATED # 2:**

I added new hosting with  /etc/apache2/sites-available/local-news-publishers.com.conf file :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /_wwwroot/lar/NewsPublisher/public
    ServerName local-news-publishers.com
    ServerAlias local-news-publishers.com

    <Directory /_wwwroot/lar/NewsPublisher/public>
    AllowOverride All
    Order Deny,Allow
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
    </Directory>

    Options FollowSymLinks
    DirectoryIndex index.php

    ErrorLog /_wwwroot/lar/NewsPublisher/storage/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /_wwwroot/lar/NewsPublisher/storage/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

and added line in /etc/hosts :

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   master-at-home

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters


...

127.0.0.7  local-quizzes.com

127.0.0.8   local-news-publishers.com
```

in .env of the app :

```
APP_URL=http://local-news-publishers.com
```

I restarted apache and clear cache of the app.

But running in my browser :

```
http://main-office.local-news-publishers.com
```

I got error in my browser :

```
This site can’t be reachedCheck if there is a typo in main-office.local-news-publishers.com.
DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN
```

But As I wrote above :

On

```
http://main-office.localhost:8000/
```

My app was opened but shows app error :

```
404 NOT FOUND
```

Which setting have I to use ?

Comment: Try using `localhost` instead of `127.0.0.1`

Comment: Please read UPDATED # 2